# Accidentally changed owner of /var system folder recursively to myself

Tags: hard-drive, macos, permission

Long story short, accidentally I ran

```
sudo chown -R myusername /var/
```

and now my mac won't boot anymore (after entering user password for hdd decryption loading bar is slowly filled and after it gets full, nothing happens). I have access to the hdd via the OS X restore utilities (Cmd+R) on startup and managed to mount my hdd using terminal. What should I do to fix this? Should I `sudo chown -R root /var/` now?

I also tried fixing the disk using Disk Utilities First aid, but that didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the system isn't bootable (in the normal sense), one easy way forward is to boot to Recovery HD and re-install the OS. There are thousands of files in `/private/var` that should be owned by `root:wheel`, `_softwareupdate:_softwareupdate`, `myusername:staff`, and hundreds `root:admin` so carpet bombing one ownership across the directories might lead to even worse breakage.

A reinstallation won't delete anything in the user and application folders but it also may or may not work - depending on if it moves aside /private and makes a new one or if it runs the equivalent of `sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /` which is a way to "repair permissions" on El Capitan if you managed to get things running again. If you have a recent backup, you could always just erase and reinstall from that.

I would try this as a first step to see if your system is salvageable. The `repair_packages` tool will run in single user mode, so that might be a nice thing to try after mounting / as read write (the syntax is provided when you boot). That tool used to be something you could run from Disk Utility, but now it's a command line tool for more specialized use apparently.

Comment: So for anyone interested, I ended up doing the following: I chowned the var folder to `root:root`, which made me able to boot the system but I could'nt use any apps except terminal and the error console was spammed with errors. I made a backup of all my data (just to be sure) and then reinstalled the system.

Answer (score 0):

What group is it chowned to? You could try adding yourself to the root group and then doing `sudo chown -R yourusername:root /var`, then make sure group access is set to whatever right now owner access is at (so if it's `rwx-r-r` make it `rwx-rwx-r`)

Comment: This might not be feasible. I have about 10k files in /private/var and there are 53 different user/group combinations present on my system. Not everything is root:wheel let alone when you start talking about changing permissions in addition to ownership.